# multiprocessing selenium python and output to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, selenium, multiprocessing

I have code that uses selenium on a list of url. Right now it's a for loop on the urls and grabs information from the url and then puts it in a mongo database. I'm trying to find a way to make it faster and thought I could multiprocess it, given every url process is independent of eachother except for inserting data into mongo. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is given that selenium isn't thread safe. Also happy to hear alternatives I'm using ubuntu Python 3.5. Psuedocode:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
collection = db['test-collection']

for urls in listToScrap:
    url= website + urls
    driver.get(url)
    #process 
    db.restaurants.insert(what_you_want,check_keys=False)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Seems like you're doing web scraping. Have you looked at [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)?

Comment: Unfortunately for this project selenium is the best most stable option